# Converting code from Python Turtle to Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I've been happily going along writing programs using Python Turtle Graphics, and occasionally super-charging that module with forays into `tkinter` when `turtle` wasn't quite up to the job. An example is shown below.

What would be the most direct translation into "non-terrible" pure `tkinter` code? Is it always recommended to use OOP with `tkinter`? If so what would my program look like using that paradigm? If not,  how would it look with just procedural `tkinter`? I've seen so many different ways to work with `tkinter` and create roots and masters etc., it's all a bit confusing. I'd like to keep the simplicity of the the approach I have used as much a possible. As usual, any help much appreciated.

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk


def do_stuff(a_turtle):
    for color in ["red", "yellow", "green"]:
        a_turtle.color(color)
        a_turtle.right(120)


def press():
    print("ouch")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.bgcolor("cyan")
    canvas = screen.getcanvas()
    button = tk.Button(canvas.master, text="Press me", command=press)
    canvas.create_window(-200, -200, window=button)
    my_lovely_turtle = turtle.Turtle(shape="turtle")
    do_stuff(my_lovely_turtle)

    turtle.done()
```

Comment: Have you looked at the source for the turtle module? Look at the functions you're using, see what they do and adapt them? https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/turtle.py

Comment: (And if you haven't noticed, you can just initialize your Tk window, add a `tk.Canvas` and point a turtle at it: `t = Turtle(canvas=...)`)

Comment: I'm sure I could quite easily get this working in Tkinter. However I want to avoid the kind of bad practices and pitfalls which can result from doing this kind of thing without guidance. That's why it would be great to see how this would be done by an expert.